# Android Studio Update from Gradle 2.2.3 to 2.3 and got Error:Could not find com.android.databinding:library:1.3.1

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I have a project recently want to update to Gradle 2.3 to setup Instant App. But after update the top level build.gradle (and the gradle-wrapper.properties setting to gradle-3.3-all.zip)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0' // was 2.2.3
        classpath 'net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:0.6'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}
```

I constantly got error :

```
Error:Could not find com.android.databinding:library:1.3.1.
Required by:
    project :app
```

Roll back to Gradle 2.2.3 fix the issue.

Anyone has idea how to fix this issue?